Show N/A for all the null columns in laravel yajra datatable?
I want to show default value like
"N/A" or dash "-" if the column value is null. Currently it displays empty column as below:

I dont want to add default value for each column individually. I want this behaviour for all my datatable classes. All datatables extend base datatable btw where I define my general configurations e.g. which should be applied to all the datatables.

You haven't provided a [mre], so we need to make some guesses. For example, you say "I dont want to add default value for each column individually". OK, so maybe the "best" approach is to handle this at the source (whatever that may be) - not in DataTables.

Handle this at the time of data creation/getting or at least at the time of rendering view.
Don't try it to accomplish with data table code.
